# imeOptions "actionNext" programmatically - how to jump to next field?

Tags: android, textview, ime, imeoptions

In layout XML it is possible to specify `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` which adds `Next` button in virtual keyboard and by clicking on it - focus jumps to the next field.

How to do this programmatically - e.g. based on some event trigger focus to go to the next field?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can use the constants from EditorInfo class for the IME options. 
like,

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

Comment: yes otherwise it inserts a new line and jumps to that =)

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? This does not automatically jump to next field.

Answer (score 31):

Search for the next focusable field and than invoke `requestFocus()`.

```
TextView nextField = (TextView)currentField.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
nextField.requestFocus();
```

Comment: This is not a true answer in reference to the title of this question, but it is technically a valid answer. Below answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @SeanGlover you should never use words like ***below*** because the position of answers keep on changing.

Answer (score 29):

Just suggestion, if you are using

```
     EditTextSample.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

it doesn't work, make sure that your EditText is using a single line.

> Eg:
>
> ```
>        editTextSample.setSingleLine();
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This should be te accepted answer. Just call setSingleLine() BEFORE setImeOptions.

Answer (score 7):

There is always necessity to add extra keys apart from default keys available in virtual **`QWERTY`** keyboard.

**Using XML**

```
<EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" 
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

**`By Programmatic Way`**

An `EditorInfo` is most useful class when you have to deal with any type of user input in your Android application.

**`IME_ACTION_DONE:`** This action performs a “done” operation for nothing to input and the IME will be closed.

```
 EditTextSample.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

For more information you may visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html

Answer (score 1):

The kotlin pendant

```
editText.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setLines(1);
editText.setSingleLine(true);
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

I solve the problem make sure with single line and go next editText when click enter

Answer (score 1):

In my case, set an imeOptions fix the problem.

```
edtAnswer.maxLines = 1
edtAnswer.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
edtAnswer.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

```
edittext.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE //for done button
```

or

```
edittext.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT //for next button
```

**But...**
you need to understand that if you are using filters for edittext then you need to set

```
edittext.setSingleLine()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the answers but [EditorAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo) worked for me!

> EditText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)

My XML layout:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input1"
            style="@style/edittext"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/input2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input2"
            style="@style/edittext"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/input1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/input3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and Kotlin code:

```
input1.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
```

Now focus moves to the ***input2*** Edittext.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the next field by using the following code:

```
BaseInputConnection inputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(editText, true);
inputConnection.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
//Use EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED if you set android:imeOptions on the EditText
```

Answer (score 0):

With Android Compose, we simply need to add the keyboard options:

```
// inside a @Composable function
val imeNextAction = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
    imeAction = ImeAction.Next
)
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    value = emailOrMobileCheckin.city,
    onValueChange = {},
    label = {
        Text(text = "City")
    },
    keyboardOptions = imeNextAction
)
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    value = emailOrMobileCheckin.state,
    onValueChange = {},
    label = {
        Text(text = "State")
    },
    keyboardOptions = imeNextAction
)
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    value = emailOrMobileCheckin.country,
    onValueChange = {},
    label = {
        Text(text = "Country")
    },
    keyboardOptions = imeNextAction
)
```