# Android imeOptions Change Programmatic

Tags: android

I have two EditText txtPassword,txtEmail  based on radiobutton change event I just hide and show txtPassword field
I just want to change ImeOptions with porgrammatic for that I wrote following code
`txtPassword.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
txtEmail.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);` 
but this is not working.  When I observe soft-keyboard this shows me done action in txtEmail (just because before radio changed only txtEmail  is visible so automatic done appear)
but after manually focous in password field and than after if I observe soft-keyboard  with email field it automatic changed it with next imeOptions.  I just want if One txtEmail is visible than it have done imeOptions  and if txtPassword,txtEmail both are visible than txtEmail  have ImeOptions next and in txtPassword it have display done imeOptions. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

`radiologin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,int checkedId) {
// checkedId is the RadioButton selected
if (checkedId == R.id.radioWithoutPassword) {
txtPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
txtEmail.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.both_corner));
txtEmail.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
}
else
{
txtEmail.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
txtPassword.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
txtPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
txtEmail.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top_corner));
}
}
});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459168/imeoptions-actionnext-programmatically-how-to-jump-to-next-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/how-do-i-handle-imeoptions-done-button-click

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
final EditText passwordEditText = new EditText(this);
    final EditText emailEditText = new EditText(this);
    RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                passwordEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                emailEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            }else{
                emailEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            }
        }
    });
```

and set `passwordEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` always.

Comment: thanks but I clearly mentioned that I already done this task but din't work

Comment: Also if password field is invisible how could you focus on it?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. what worked with me is adding `android:singleLine="true"`and i dint mention any imeOptions or next focus values. i got the expected result. in first editText keyboard shows next if another editText is visible else it shows done :-p