# How to set a few imeOptions programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have `FrameLayout` container in which I want to add dynamically `EditText`. I need to set two `imeOptions`: `IME_ACTION_DONE` and `IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI` in this same time but I have problem how to do it programmatically. My solution override my `imeOptions` (I now that is good behavior :) but I try everything)

And my secound question: How to set focus after create EditText programmatically? This method `editText.requestFocus();` dosen't work for me. I want to open keyboard after `postCardContainer.addView(editText);`

```
  postCardContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = (int) event.getY()-50;
            params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX()-50;

            EditText editText = new EditText(NewPostcardActivity.this);
            editText.setSingleLine();
            editText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
            editText.requestFocus();
            editText.setLayoutParams(params);
            editText.setCursorVisible(true);
            editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);

            postCardContainer.addView(editText);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501426/android-imeoptions-change-programmatic

Comment: No, I want to set IME_ACTION_DONE and IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI on one EditText object not diffrent. Two attrs on one object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459168/imeoptions-actionnext-programmatically-how-to-jump-to-next-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/how-do-i-handle-imeoptions-done-button-click

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try like as below.

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```