# EditText flow, what determines the action button on virtual keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 2 same identical EditText:

```
<EditText        
android:id="@+id/card_num_edit"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:ems="13"
android:inputType="phone"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="14sp"
/>
```

Other one:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/phoneRegEdit"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:ems="13"
android:inputType="phone"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="14sp" />
```

One of them have a **"next one"** action button when the virtual keyboard shows up, the other have an **"ok"** action button.

The **"next one"** is passing focus to the next EditText but the **"ok"** is doing nothing just hiding the virtual keyboard.

[image]
[image]

**My question is,** what conditions decide which button is showing up? In my opinion Android have a huge deficiency with EditText's focus flow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459168/imeoptions-actionnext-programmatically-how-to-jump-to-next-field/30010936#30010936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done by IME_OPTIONs [More info here](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/using-edit-text-ime-option-in-android-app/)

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/some_edittext"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"><!-- Here you set whatever option you want -->
```

Comment: I think s/he use actionDone instead of actionSend