# Perform action done to Editext programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want, create a Button that when pressed, will perform ACTION_DONE on the EditText. Currently I make softkeyboard  hidden and create a custom keyboard in the application, I have tried searching on google but it doesn't get the search results I want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743182/4168607

Comment: awesome, that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this in your buttons on click listener, LMK if this works

editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);